# Is it possible, to use GridView for activities?

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity

I want show activity on `gridView` like screenshoot.
When I click on item it open activity, when I click back it show `gridView` again.
When I click `newItem` button it create new activity and show it on `gridView`.

Is it posible or I need use something other, not `gridView`?

Comment: aren't you confusing the concept of activities and views?

Comment: Are you trying to create something like a desktop with icons or the recent apps list?

Comment: I think your terminology is a bit off here. I'll rephrase part of your question. You should say "When I click the newItem button it creates a new item that shows up in the existing gridview". And yes you can do that, just add a new item to your adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I want something like tabs, but not tabhost, because tabhost is most idiotic thing ever seen. When I open new tab with new webView it show ads from webview in old tab. And when I open new  tabs I can't close it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, and it's quite simple too.

1 - Create an activity named "GridHome.java" for instance. Make the layout for this activity be only a GridView. 
2 - Fill the gridview with pre-loaded images from your other activities. Say for instance, take a screenshot of the other activities and store them as PNG, then add them as drawables into your application, and lastly add them to the gridview via a customer adapter. 
3 - Set an OnItemClickListener to the gridview so that when the user clicks on one, you can start a new intent to the activity you wish to open. For this one you can add a method like this to your custom grid adapter:

```
public String getItemActivityName(int pos) {
    return activityNames.get(pos);
}
```

where "activityNames" is an Array of strings corresponding to the activities you have on the grid view.

And from the "GridHome.java" you would do this to the GridVIew:

```
mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.home_grid);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            String activityName = mAdapter.getActivityName(position);       
            if (activityName.equals(ACTIVITY_ONE) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityOne.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }               
        }           
    });
```

Where ACTIVITY_ONE is a constant that represents the name of one your activities.

```
private static final String ACTIVITY_ONE = "Contacts";
private static final String ACTIVITY_TWO = "Groups";
```

And so forth and on.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want it gridView in sliding drawer, because I want navigate in this activities. I mean, when I open Actvity ONE, do something in this activity, then I slide up gridView open Activty TWO and do something there. Question is: How to don't stop Activity ONE, because I want go back to there and continue, what I begin.